# Publish scripts not generated by visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I am trying to figure out how to best deploy my web apps to azure using something like Jenkins. So I thought i should investigate publishing using deploy scripts.
In all tutorials on deploy scripts for azure you should start with some scripts generated by visual studio when creating your web app. This doesn't seem to happen for me. Am I missing something or is that just not true anymore?
I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am building ASP.Net web apps. 
According to the tutorials I am supposed to get a folder on solution level called "PublishScripts".

Comment: Same problem but with VS2017. Did you solve this?

Comment: I ended up deploying with msbuild and making my own scripts

Comment: Thank you, I was about to do the same.